# Javascript's date object toLocaleTimeString adds an hour

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a timer from when the user clicks a button.
To do this I tried to calculate the difference between two `date` objects. When I output the difference, it works. However the`toLocaleTimeString` call returns a string with an extra hour added:

```js
var start;
var timer;
function myTimer() {
  var current = new Date();
  var difference = new Date(current - start);
  console.log(difference.getTime(), difference.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language));
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = difference;
  document.getElementById("timer2").innerHTML = difference.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
}
start = new Date();
timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
draw();
```

```html
<h1 id="timer"></h1>
<h1 id="timer2"></h1>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish here? Is it simply a timer you are trying to make or is the date important to this?

Comment: @somethinghere Was in the process of typing the same comment! Interested to see the desired output.

Comment: @somethinghere Good question! A timer, but I like the format `toLocaleTimeString` creates so if there is an alternative that matches the format I'd be happy to use it :) (Providing it's fairly concise, I don't want tonnes of of code for something so simple)

Comment: The format you can easily do by combining all the functions Date has to offers like `Date.getMinutes()` etc...

Comment: @somethinghere I tried this but to format hours,minutes,seconds to 2 digits adds even more code to the mess of modulo of minutes by 60 etc. If you can do this in a concise manner, please add it as an answer :)

Comment: They already do it for you, heres the description on MDN (with some replacement to generalise it): `The get[timeUnit]() method returns the [timeUnit] for the specified date, according to local time.` - Check out my answer, I ahve updated it with my own formatted string using the standard methods and it does exactly what you want it to do - modules and all, built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the time zone as UTC in the `options` argument. Otherwise, the `difference` date will be adjusted to the user agent's time zone.

```
document.getElementById("timer2").innerHTML = difference.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' });
```

Read more on the `options` argument and `toLocaleTimeString` in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Using_options).

```js
var start;
var timer;
function myTimer() {
  var current = new Date();
  var difference = new Date(current - start);
  console.log(difference.getTime(), difference.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language));
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = difference;
  document.getElementById("timer2").innerHTML = difference.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, { timeZone: 'UTC', hour12: false });
}
start = new Date();
timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
draw();
```

```html
<h1 id="timer"></h1>
<h1 id="timer2"></h1>
```

Comment: If I replace the code in the OP's snippet with yours, the same problem occurs. I am guessing this has to do with JS not knowing the difference between BST, GMT, etc..

Comment: @somethinghere Did you run the snippet (hidden by default) in my answer? The second timer counts up from 00:00:00 which I believe is the intent.

Comment: I think the issue is that JS uses my local time zone - you should actually never JS for time functions like that as it's not very robust. I am seeing the `01:00:38` in my snippet, not `00`.

Comment: @somethinghere Strange, I see all zeroes. Specifying `timeZone: 'UTC'` in the `toLocaleTimeString` call should explicitly use UTC, which would be 00:00:00. I'm starting to get the sneaking suspicion that this has something to do with DST.

Comment: Yeah that's my suspicion as well. For this kind of thing, its better to use moment.js timezone or something similar. I have posted an answer that counts using `Date.now()`, which always gives the right result in this case.

Comment: @somethinghere Agreed on the use of a library. But, your answer starts the timer at 19:00:00 which is the same result I see in the question. I am in GMT-5.

Comment: Thats seems entirely impossible as `Date.now() - future Date.now()` will always be the passed time, regardless of timezone etc... Since we are using a different timezone this should work. The problem is testing it, I guess, as our computers are all in our timezones :) I do have to say that 19:00 is a _very_ odd time to start with...

Comment: This appears to continue working even when I change the time-zone on my clock too, nice and concise too, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the problems with JS and timezones, you are better of using something like moment.js's timezone (http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to do correct conversions (that keep in mind the shift of BST, GMT, differences between countries, etc..). For the purpose of your timer, the following would work as well, and is more accurate as well as simpler to reason about:

```js
// Use Date.now() to get the time in milliseconds for this local computer
var start = Date.now();
var time  = new Date();
// This function will prepend a 0 to a number lower than 10
function prependZero(v){
  if(v < 9) return '0' + v;
  else return v;
}
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Calculate the difference using the computers local time strings
    var difference = new Date(Date.now() - start);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = new Date();
    // Now use the Date mnethods to get the correct output:
    document.getElementById("timer2").innerHTML = prependZero(difference.getHours()) + ':' + prependZero(difference.getMinutes()) + ':' + prependZero(difference.getSeconds());
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="timer"></h1>
<h1 id="timer2"></h1>
```

Comment: Strange, this still doesn't count up from 00:00:00 for me: http://i.imgur.com/a0POn3Y.png

Comment: @DrewGaynor Ahhh Please note that the time displayed is your local computer locale string, its the string below that displays the passed time, which is the issue we are dealing with here. (As in: the resulting calculations gives us the accurate passing of the timer regardless of the locale)

Comment: The screenshot is of the contents of `#timer2`. It shows up as hour 19 because `difference` starts at hour 0. Five hours back from 0 is 19. My updated answer works with any timezone I change my machine to. I'm curious if you still see it counting up from hour 1?

Comment: When I change my machine to London time (which I am guessing you are in), it counts up from 0, as does my answer at this point. However, yours shifts as I change to other time zones. Golly, time zones are just the best!

Comment: @DrewGaynor The shift is not unexpected, I thought the idea was to create a timer and not focus on the date. In my timezone, however, your snippet still runs +1... Dates are making my head spin. We should ask the OP for the exact reason he needs this and what he wants out of this before continuing because, yes, timezones are a goddamn hassle.